# I was deported from the UK in 2010, after spending 8 months in prison, can I go back now in 2024?

Tags: visas, uk, family, student-visas, deportation

I was deported from the UK in 2010, after spending 8 months in prison, now in 2024 I would like to go back to the UK for studying with my family? Can I go back to the UK?

Comment: Which visa did you have when you were deported? You said you wanted to go to UK to study with the family. Is your family already in the UK? This is very ambiguous statement. Can you clarify?